# Sorting an int array, tied to a string array in Java

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

I have two arrays:

```
int[] intArray = new int[]{point1,point2,point3,point4};

String[] strArray = new String[]{worda,wordb,wordc,wordd};
```

Now, I want to sort intArray in numerical order, such that strArray follows the same order. I'm sure this is a common problem, but I can't get it to work. I made a TreeMap and added the values in from each array. Shouldn't a TreeMap automatically sort by the key, intArray[]? It doesn't appear to work.

```
        TreeMap theMap = new TreeMap();

        theMap.put(intArray, strArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a TreeMap should work fine.  However instead of adding both arrays add the each pair of values.

```
theMap.put(point1, worda);
theMap.put(point2, wordb);
theMap.put(point3, wordc);
theMap.put(point4, wordd);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing how a `TreeMap` is used. `TreeMap` keeps the keys sorted. In your case you have one key - `intArray` so there is nothing to be sorted. You have to put every pair into the map: `theMap.put(intArray[i], strArray[i])` for every possible `i`.

By the way, if it is only for the sorting you don't need obligatory a `TreeMap`. You can make a list of a class which wraps a point and a string and then sort it with `Collections.sort(list)`. Of course you have to implement `Comparable` interface.

Comment: This assumes all int values are unique, any duplicates will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i< intArray.length; i++)
  theMap.put(intArray[i],strArray[i])
```

Comment: you may want to check before iteration `if(intArray.length>strArray.length) throw new IllegalStateException()`

Comment: It will throw an exception any way so I am not sure the extra check is needed.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey. Yes It will, I wanted to convey that be aware. :)

Comment: I would add *assert intArray.length == strArray.length;* to convey this.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey ah, yeah. This is better. Thanks. I improved a bit. :) I'd almost forgaotten that _assert_ is also a tool available.